# How to print the value of dictionary from the file using python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a dictionary in a file and print the name value from the file

```
di = {'elk': [{'url_1': 'localhost:8080/api/running',
                                 'url_2': 'localhost:8080/api/',
                                 'name': 'cat',
                                 'method': 'GET'}],
 'a': [{'url_1': 'localhost:8080/api/running',
                              'url_2': 'localhost:8080/api/',
                              'name': 'mouse',
                              'method': 'GET'}]}
```

#Read a file

```
import os
with open('g.txt','r') as fh:
    fh_n = fh.read()
```

#Save in to list

```
test = []
for k,v in di.items():
    test.append(v[0]['name'])
test
```

> > ['cat', 'mouse']

Comment: *a dictionary in a file* - trying to parse `.py` file from another py file? elaborate your question

Comment: If you have a dict in a.py and you want to consume it in b.py just use import - no need to do file open.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: You should consider using .json file instead of text file, and take a look at https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-xml-json/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import ast

with open('g.txt','r') as fh:
    fh_n = fh.read()

#first split string and convert into dictionary
data = ast.literal_eval(fh_n.split("=")[1].strip())

#or
#di = remove from text file
#ast.literal_eval(fh_n)

name = [i[0]['name'] for i in data.values()]
print(name)
```

O/P:

```
['cat', 'mouse']
```

OR

convert text file data into json file
`g.json` file

```
[{
  "di": {
    "elk": [
      {
        "url_1": "localhost:8080/api/running",
        "url_2": "localhost:8080/api/",
        "name": "cat",
        "method": "GET"
      }
    ],
    "a": [
      {
        "url_1": "localhost:8080/api/running",
        "url_2": "localhost:8080/api/",
        "name": "mouse",
        "method": "GET"
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

`.py` file

```
import json

with open('g.json') as fh:
   data = json.load(fh)

name = [i[0]['name'] for i in data[0]['di'].values()]
print(name)
```

O/P:

```
['cat', 'mouse']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json` to get your result:-

```
di = {'elk': [{'url_1': 'localhost:8080/api/running',
                             'url_2': 'localhost:8080/api/',
                             'name': 'cat',
                             'method': 'GET'}],
             'a': [{'url_1': 'localhost:8080/api/running',
                          'url_2': 'localhost:8080/api/',
                          'name': 'mouse',
                          'method': 'GET'}]}
import json
file = open('g.json', 'w')
json.dump(di, file)  # Saving di into g.json file
file.close()

file_open = open('g.json', 'r+')
my_di = json.load(file_open)  # Loading the saved g.json file
file_open.close()

print(type(di))
print(di)
```

I hope it may help you.